# RuntimeError: unable to perform operation on the handler is closed. Django and Flutter

Tags: python, django, flutter, websocket

I am new to WebSocket programming and Dart/Flutter programming, but not new to Django/Python. This toy project is my self-studying in free time

I pick awesome Django boilerplate from [here](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) and follow along the channels's tutorial [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html)

Web browser Chrome be able to reproduce the example. Next I try Flutter [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets)

I expect user in the mobile be able to listen to the message and send message.
But my mobile can only receive the message from web user.

**Problem:**
When the mobile send the message. Django disconnect its connection and raises this error in terminal

```sh
django        | ERROR:    closing handshake failed
django        | Traceback (most recent call last):
django        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py", line 232, in handler
django        |     await self.close()
django        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 779, in close
django        |     await asyncio.shield(self.close_connection_task)
django        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 1309, in close_connection
django        |     self.transport.write_eof()
django        |   File "uvloop/handles/stream.pyx", line 696, in uvloop.loop.UVStream.write_eof
django        |   File "uvloop/handles/handle.pyx", line 159, in uvloop.loop.UVHandle._ensure_alive
django        | RuntimeError: unable to perform operation on <TCPTransport closed=True reading=False 0x55ed26012b80>; the handler is closed
django        | ERROR 2021-09-25 11:05:01,093 server 11 140336674826048 closing handshake failed
django        | Traceback (most recent call last):
django        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py", line 232, in handler
django        |     await self.close()
django        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 779, in close
django        |     await asyncio.shield(self.close_connection_task)
django        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 1309, in close_connection
django        |     self.transport.write_eof()
django        |   File "uvloop/handles/stream.pyx", line 696, in uvloop.loop.UVStream.write_eof
django        |   File "uvloop/handles/handle.pyx", line 159, in uvloop.loop.UVHandle._ensure_alive
django        | RuntimeError: unable to perform operation on <TCPTransport closed=True reading=False 0x55ed26012b80>; the handler is closed
django        | INFO:     connection closed
```

**Question:**
How to solve this error?

**Reproduce the error:**

1. checkout `master` from [repository](https://github.com/elcolie/try_websocket)
2. `docker-compose.yml -f loca.lyml up`
3. Run the Flutter from `study_websocket`
4. Webbrowser go to `http://localhost:8000/chat/cat/`. I put hard code `cat` in the channel` url
5. webbrowser send message
6. mobile send message. At this point

Answer (score 0):

I have to use `json.encode()` my payload before send to WebSocket

`_channel.sink.add(json.encode({'message': _controller.text}))`